# Is it possible to launch Tableau Desktop application from a browser?

Tags: web, desktop-application, tableau-api

Is it possible to launch Tableau Desktop application from a browser?

Scenario : A web page with a web form (few rows and columns simulating a table), submit button posts form element values as JSON, creates and opens a Tableau Desktop app, ready for doing visualizations.

Comment: If it's truly a *desktop* application, the practical answer is "no."  Javascript does not allow you to launch arbitrary executables.

Comment: As Robert Harvey said, the answer is No to launching an exe. But Tableau online and server come with web authoring capabilities. You can easily launch the web authoring tool from within a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Web edit is your option.

Tableau desktop requires a license so even if you could do it, you would be allowing all users to share the same license or buying a license for every single user.